# Querying and grouping multiple column attributes e.g. Books with many authors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query some book titles, languages and author names, but some of the books have multiple authors. I want to get all # of authors on the title of the book once.I have 3 tables: `bibrecs` which hold the books' data such as `bookid , title` etc,`authors` with the `aid` and `authname` of the author and `bibauthors`which connects the other two,having `bookid` and `aid`.
 In my code for instance

```
select title, lang, author
from authors, bibrecs, bibauthors
where bibauthors.aid = authors.aid
    and bibauthors.bibno = bibrecs.bibno    
group by title, lang, author
```

I get what I need but if a book has two authors for example it shows something like:

```
title1 author1
title1 author2
```

and I want to have it like title1 author1,author2..

Any ideas?
The results i get e.g.

```
title                                   lang   author
John von Neumann and modern economics   eng    Chakravarty, Sukhamoy
John von Neumann and modern economics   eng    Dore, Mohammed H. I.
John von Neumann and modern economics   eng    Goodwin, Richard Murphey
```

but the desired one would be

```
title                                   lang   author
John von Neumann and modern economics   eng    Chakravarty, Sukhamoy Dore, 
                                               Mohammed H. I., Goodwin, Richard 
                                               Murphey
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results (as formatted text).

Comment: `JOIN`. `JOIN`. `JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i suppose i have to use join,but how? :p

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, as your version, does not support STRING_AGG, you can go for FOR XML PATH for string concatenation.

```sql
DECLARE @author TABLE (aid INT, author VARCHAR(30));
DECLARE @bibrecs TABLE (bibno INT, title VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @bibauthors TABLE (bibno INT, aid INT)

INSERT INTO @author
VALUES (1, 'Chakravarty, Sukhamoy')
, (2, 'Dore, Mohammed H. I.')
, (3, 'Goodwin, Richard Murphey')

INSERT INTO @bibrecs
VALUES (1, 'John von Neumann and modern economics')

INSERT INTO @bibauthors
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)

SELECT obr.title, STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + a.author
            FROM @bibrecs AS br
            JOIN @bibauthors AS ba ON ba.bibno = br.bibno
            JOIN @author AS a ON ba.aid = a.aid
            WHERE br.bibno = obr.bibno
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS authors
FROM @bibrecs AS obr
GROUP BY obr.title, obr.bibno
```

**Result Set**

```
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                 title                 |                               authors                               |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| John von Neumann and modern economics | Chakravarty, Sukhamoy,Dore, Mohammed H. I.,Goodwin, Richard Murphey |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```